# Socket io: Cannot for loop or use array methods on socket.rooms

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to write:

```
socket.on("create-room", (roomID)=> socket.room = roomID)

let userS_selected_room = 'f2eac135-eafd-49e1-adc7-c89351703896';

for(room in socket.rooms){
  if(room === userS_selected_room) {do_stuff()}
}
```

I don't understand these:  Map(4), [Set]

console.log(socket.rooms)

```
Set(4) {
  'zBROv1Lug0XhoQxCAAAB',
  'room1',
  '9e9ecaa6-473a-43a6-9ab7-60ff034ab614',
  '1dc1547c-d265-4d5a-bd3f-9a5d37bf883a'
}
```

console.log(socket)/

```
...
    rooms: Map(4) {
      '6Otk--hk5SHOVRcrAAAD' => [Set], //socket id 
      'room1' => [Set],
      'f2eac135-eafd-49e1-adc7-c89351703896' => [Set], //this is room id
      '91fdf074-a1e7-493b-97b9-5a6050095697' => [Set] //this is room id
    },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is telling you that `socket.rooms` is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, which maps keys (like `'6Otk--hk5SHOVRcrAAAD'`) to [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) objects. You can loop through the map using [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (not `for-in`):

```
for (const [roomid, room] of sockets.rooms) {
    // ...here, `roomid` will be the ID of the room, and
    // `room` will be a `Set`...
}
```

If you don't need the room IDs, you can use the `values` method and loop its result:

```
for (const room] of sockets.rooms.values()) {
    // ...here, `room` will be a `Set`...
}
```

Or if you have a room ID, get the `Set` for that room via `get`:

```
const room = socket.rooms.get(roomID);
```

You'll have to refer to whatever library you're using to populate `socket.rooms` in order to find out what the `Set` objects contain, but to loop through the elements in the set, you'd use `for-of` again:

```
for (const whatever of room) {
    // ...use `whatever`...
}
```

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/#implementation-details - I was reading this

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't realize Socket.io itself has this room concept now. Cool!